# set/unset user presence in IRC

Tags: irc

I am programming an IRC gateway to another protocol, and I want my IRC server (the gateway) to notify the IRC client when other users are connected or disconnected.

This feature is supported by my IRC client (Quassel) : it shows me when a user set himself as `/away`, but I can't figure out what command my IRC server must send to set/unset user presence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ideally implement the IRCv3 spec away-notify: http://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/away-notify-3.1.html

Otherwise your client has to spam WHO polls often to get the latest status of users.